# random pick item or value based on groupby date

Tags: pandas, numpy, random

How to randomly pick 3 variables in var1, groupby 'DATE', sum it, then do several simulation?

```
df =
             
    DATE       var1 
    2023-01-31  1
    2023-01-31  2
    2023-01-31  3
    2023-01-31  4
    2023-01-31  5
    2023-02-28  6
    2023-02-28  7
    2023-02-28  8
    2023-02-28  9
    2023-02-28  10

    Simulation 1 =
    2023-01-31 = (1+3+5) = 9
    2023-02-28 = (6+7+10) = 23

    simulation 2
    2023-01-31 = (1+2+5) = 8
    2023-02-28 = (9+7+10) = 26
    
    simulation n.......
```

let's say we do 10 simulation for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
out = df.groupby('DATE').agg(lambda g: g.sample(n=3).sum())
```

Example output:

```
            var1
DATE            
2023-01-31     8
2023-02-28    27
```

If you want to repeat the process, use a loop:

```
N = 10

for i in range(N):
    print(f'simulation {i+1}')
    print(df.groupby('DATE').agg(lambda g: g.sample(n=3).sum()))
```

###### create a DataFrame from the repeated sampling:

```
N = 10
query = 'DATE == "2023-01-31"'

out = pd.concat({i+1: df.query(query).groupby('DATE').agg(lambda g: g.sample(n=3).sum())
                 for i in range(N)
                 }, names=['simulation'])
```

Example output:

```
                       var1
simulation DATE            
1          2023-01-31     8
2          2023-01-31    10
3          2023-01-31    12
4          2023-01-31     8
5          2023-01-31     9
6          2023-01-31    10
7          2023-01-31    11
8          2023-01-31    12
9          2023-01-31    10
10         2023-01-31     6
```

Comment: Hi mozway, thanks for the solution. sorry for asking again. How i can present the information (the value) for every simulation on date '2023-01-31' into pandas dataframe ?

Comment: `df.groupby('DATE').agg(lambda g: g.sample(n=3).sum())` is a DataFrame. I'll update with an example for multiple simulations